# Wordpress + WooCommerce | MySQL Skills Inadequate

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

What I am trying to do is create a page where multiple dropdown select menus are present. Each menu would contain a product type (e.g CPU, Motherboard, Graphics Card, etc.) with all products under that category displayed next to their prices. So, what I have come to do is to create a page template with custom PHP in it to meet the end goal. Here is how it plays out:

1. Set a category name as a variable
2. Grab any "term_id" that matches a given category name from the "wplz_terms" table - send the entire return to a correctly formatted array.
3. Resolve all of the "term_id(s)" to "product_id(s)" in the table "wplz_term_relationships".
4. Resolve all items that are listed with the "product_id(s)" returned above by querying "wplz_posts" and selecting each matching product's name.
5. Select "meta_value" from "wplz_postmeta" where "post_id" matches the "product_id(s)" returned above and "meta_key" is equal to "_price" - then take the results of steps 4 and 5 and push them into an array that holds the names and corresponding prices for every product returned.

Here is my code so far. I've spent time trying to figure out "LEFT JOIN" (which is what I think I'm looking for)

```
/ Return all products in the category "CPU"
$term = 'CPU';

// Resolve Term to Term ID(s)
$query = "
    SELECT
    term_id
    FROM wplz_terms
    WHERE name = $term
";

// Execute the Query
$return = $wpdb->get_results($query, OBJECT);

// Properly Format the Result for an Array
$array = json_decode(json_encode($return),true);

// Flatten Array to Simple Array Function
function array_flatten_recursive($array) { 
   if (!$array) return false;
   $flat = array();
   $RII = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($array));
   foreach ($RII as $value) $flat[] = $value;
   return $flat;
}
$flat = array_flatten_recursive($array);

// Format for Next MySQL Query
$in = implode(',', $flat);

// Resolve Term ID to Object ID(s) 
$query = "
    SELECT
    object_id
    FROM wplz_term_relationships
    WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN ($in)
";

// Execute the Query
$return = $wpdb->get_results($query, OBJECT);

// Properly Format the Result for an Array
$array = json_decode(json_encode($return),true);

// Refresh $flat Value
$flat = array_flatten_recursive($array);

// Format for Next MySQL Query
$in = implode(',', $flat);

// Resolve Products by the resulting Object ID(s)
$query = "
    SELECT
    id,
    post_title
    FROM wplz_posts 
    WHERE id IN ($in)
";

// Execute the Query
$return = $wpdb->get_results($query, OBJECT);

// Properly Format the Result for an Array
$array = json_decode(json_encode($return),true);
```

Comment: are the products in a custom post type or are they just post_type "post" ?

Comment: For all products in WooCommerce, the post_type is set as "product" - while of course pages are set as "page".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I'm understanding you correctly, you want to display a list of posts filtered by a taxonomy term. This is something WordPress has built into `WP_Query`:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $term
        )
    )
) );

while ( $query->have_posts() ):
    $query->the_post();
    // Your HTML would go here, or better yet, use a template part:
    get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
endwhile;

wp_reset_postdata(); // Reloads original query, very important!
```

And if you wanted to filter on more than one term, just replace `$terms` with an array of term slugs.

---

**Display results as a dropdown menu**

Assuming the query has been set up like the above code, your template code would look *something* like this:

```
<select name="product_choice" id="product_chooser">

<?php
    while ( $query->have_posts() ):
        $query->the_post();
        printf(
            '<option value="%d">%s - %s</option>',
            get_the_ID(),
            get_the_title(),
            get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_price', true )
        );
    endwhile;

    wp_reset_postdata();
?>

</select>
```

Of course, you'll need to modify the name and ID of the select to fit with the rest of your code, but that should get you started.

Comment: Yes so filtering and displaying the products is not really where I'm stuck at the moment, it's retrieving each product's price from the "wplz_postmeta" table and including that in the same array that the product's name is in... That way I can use a `foreach` statement to simply loop through the array to populate the select dropdown options.

Comment: In the template, and within the loop, you can use `get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_price', true)` to retrieve the data you are looking for.

Comment: That's great, thank you so much for your help. However now the page shows full listings of each product, where my attempt has been to simply have the data in an array, and then for each category have a dropdown select in HTML with only the product name and price in it...

Comment: In that case, you're template file should be outputting `<options>`. I will update my answer with an example.

Comment: Thank you again friend. :) If I could press my luck, is there a way that the results could be listed in alphabetical order perhaps? It's becoming increasingly apparent that I need to study the back end to wordpress better... :P

Comment: Heh, no problem. We all have to start somewhere. The answer is yes, by adding `'orderby' => 'title'` and `'order' => 'ASC'` into the query args. There's all sorts of cool things you can do with `WP_Query`: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: And I just noticed that I am using `wp_reset_query` instead of `wp_reset_postdata` -- Oops. I've updated my answer again to use the correct function.